# angular input type datetime-local validation

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular application for date time  selection I am using input  type="datetime-local".

```
 <input id="field_bookingTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="bookingTime" [(ngModel)]="bookingTime"
   required/>
```

Now I need to disable the dates that are previous to current date and the dates that are 3 days next to current date. For example for min, I have added validations as shown below. But the validations are not working, still the previous dates are getting enabled in the displayed calendar.

```
currentDate = new Date();

     <input [min]="currentDate" id="field_bookingTime" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="bookingTime" [(ngModel)]="bookingTime"
       required/>
```

Comment: Is the input to be used in any [Angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)?

Comment: Yes, I am using angular template driven forms

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing a [custom validator](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html) for the form control. Min and max have bad [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), this goes for datetime-local aswell though.

```
    function dateValidator(c: FormControl) {
        // Not sure if c will come in as a date or if we have to convert is somehow
        const today = new Date();
        if(c.value > today) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return {dateValidator: {valid: false}};
        }
    }
    ...
    myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        date: ['', dateValidator]
    })
    ...
```

Comment: Or use the Angular Material teams [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) alternatively

Answer (score 2):

`<input>` elements of type `datetime-local` accepts values for min and max as string in `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm` format only. Since `new Date()` returns a string which is not in the correct format min and max won't work. Just convert the date to the correct format like this.

```
currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 16);
```

Here we are converting the date to the desired format first by converting it to a *simplified* extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long and then removing the chars after `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`

Comment: Clever. This doesn't appear to work for showing the locale time tho. Only GMT?

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your date with dashes:

Example:

```
pipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

minDate = new Date();
minDateOut = pipe.transform(minDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

maxDate = new Date(minDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3));
maxDateOut = pipe.transform(maxDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');


<input 
    [min]="minDateOut" 
    [max]="maxDateOut" 
    id="field_bookingTime" 
    type="datetime-local" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="bookingTime" 
    [(ngModel)]="bookingTime"
    required/>
```

Or just use any other date format without spaces...

Comment: I have internationalization support for my project,so by predefining 'en-US', may effect other regions

Comment: You can get locale like this:

let locale = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;

Or

Just use another method to format date string, you don't have to use DatePipe...